# Using Nunjucks in Feathers

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I have a Feathers app. This weekend I decided to migrate the app from Swig to [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/). In an attempt to do this, I have the following in my ./routes/index.js file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function() {
    const app = this;
    const path = require('path');
    const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');    
    const home = require('./home');

    nunjucks.configure('views', {
        express : app,
        noCache : app.get('env') === 'development',
    });

    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'html');    

    // Configure the routes.
    app.configure(home);
};
```

My Feathers app starts fine. However, when I navigate to the home page, I get redirected to the ./auth/failure screen and get an error that says "Login Failed". Please remember, this worked just fine when I was using Swig. So, I decided to replace my view with the most basic of HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hello</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

So, I know that there's nothing in the template engine itself. It has to do with how it's being used at runtime though. Yet, I can't figure out how to get a more detailed error message to understand what's causing the error.

How can I use Nunjucks in my Feathers app in place of Swig?

Comment: I think that `nunjucks` is not found template and throw error. `Feather` catch error and interpret it as auth error. Try set absolute path for `nunjucks`.

Comment: @AikonMogwai Thank you for your comment. Can you please explain what you mean by set an absolute path for nunjucks? Do you mean set the absolute path in the `const nunjucks = ...` statement? Or elsewhere?

Comment: Try e.g. `d:/smth-path/project-path/views` instead `path.join(__dirname, '../views')` to exclude case with incorrect path of templates. Also you can use domains to catch async errors.

Comment: @AikonMogwai I just trying to use the absolute path. Unfortunately, that did not work.  What do you mean in regards to using domains to catch async errors? Is there some documentation for that? If I could just get some insight into what's happening, I'm confident that I could resolve it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html but now it's deprecated functionality =/ I'm not sure but: you passed `app` to `nunjucks.configure(...)` and perhaps `Feathers`-app is not realized required method (see `/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js`)